# Error related with msvcr100.dll when hosting on Plesk

Tags: asp.net, hosting, plesk

I've made an application that's work perfectly when running it using Visual Studio or when hosting in using local IIS, but when i host it on Plesk and try to run it it gives me the following error...

```
`Error loading msvcr100.dll (ErrorCode: 5)`
```

**Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[Exception: Error loading msvcr100.dll (ErrorCode: 5)]
   SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssembly(String nativeBinaryPath, String assemblyName) +116
   SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(String rootApplicationPath) +30
   CMS.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +58
[HttpException (0x80004005): Error loading msvcr100.dll (ErrorCode: 5)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9936485
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
[HttpException (0x80004005): Error loading msvcr100.dll (ErrorCode: 5)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9950728
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Try to install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999

Comment: i don't think it would help, i don't have access to the hosting machine..only ftp file upload

Answer (score 1):

`ErrorCode: 5` is an *Access Denied* meaning the process that is running cannot access the file to load the libraries (for example, IIS) acording to [this list of error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), that says:

> ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED 5 (0x5) Access is denied

You can read more information via the docs refering the [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) that says:

> To obtain an error string for system error codes, use the
>   FormatMessage function. For a complete list of error codes provided by
>   the operating system, see System Error Codes.

Comment: This answer is correct.  This happened to me when my IIS process was trying to load the same dll.  To fix the problem, I had to browse to the folder where the dll was located, and add "Authenticated Users" with Read and Execute permissions.  This gives IIS the needed permissions to load the dll.

Answer (score 0):

As Zaki already said, try to reinstall Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package, as additional step I recommend to delete installed package first.

Ask your hosting provider for technical support.